# Oracle Stored Procedure not working (where in string)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, where-in

Here is my entire Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "CTI"."TEMP_DIVISION"
(
    pDivisionList in varchar2,
    out_cursor out SYS_REFCURSOR
)
as
begin
  open out_cursor for
  SELECT distinct CTA_DIVISION
  FROM cti_account 
  WHERE CTA_DIVISION in (pDivisionList);  
END;
```

If I pass in TPA, it returns TPA as 1 row (correct).  If I pass in CFL, it returns CFL as 1 row (correct). However, what I would like to do, is pass in TPA,CFL and have it run like WHERE CTA_DIVISION in ('TPA','CFL') returning 2 rows of data, but that's not happening. It's not returning any rows.  What do I need to change to be able to pass that string in and get 2 rows returned? TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle stored procedure with parameters for IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242771/oracle-stored-procedure-with-parameters-for-in-clause)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can adapt [Oracle: passing a list as bind variable](http://knol.google.com/k/oracle-passing-a-list-as-bind-variable) to suit your case.

To make the varchar2 work as a list or single value, you'll need to parse the `pDivisionList` into an array (of possibly one value) and pass it on to another procedure (that can be defined within your procedure.)

WRT to the solution of @frustratedwithformsdesigner , dynamic sql is susceptible to sql-injection. Take care with such solutions.

Comment: It seems the key is `WHERE empno in (SELECT * FROM   TABLE( CAST ( ? as NUMBER_LIST_TYPE ) ) )`... very clever (though I've never tried it)!! Is there a minimum version this trick needs?

Comment: That worked.  Also, this helped http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:110612348061

Comment: @frustratedwithformsdesigner Correct. I should have highlighted that. I'm not sure but CAST may have been introduced in 11g. The TYPE has been around for quite a long time.

Answer (score 0):

This can probably be done with dynamic SQL. Build the query like this:

```
sql_str := 'SELECT distinct CTA_DIVISION
  FROM cti_account 
  WHERE CTA_DIVISION in ('||pDivisionList||')';
```

and then use [`execute immediate`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm) on it. Of course, you'll have to make sure that `pDivisionList` is formatted as `"'a','b','c'"`.

Of course, dynamic SQL has potential SQL-injection problems, so make sure you have full control over what gets into `pDivisionList`.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is:

```
SELECT distinct CTA_DIVISION
FROM cti_account 
WHERE INSTR(','||pDivisionList||',', ','||CTA_DIVISION||',') > 0;
```