# concatenate multiple clobs withing Oracle Procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, clob

I have an Oracle procedure that is going to accept multiple values within a parameter. Part of the procedure will run a select statement putting the results of the parameter in the where clause and placing the concatenated CLOBs into a variable. I am currently using the query below in the procedure but when I run it I get the error below.

```
If CLOB_ID is not null then
    SELECT cast((collect(CLOB_TEXT) )as CLOB )
    into v_MessageBody 
    FROM MESSAGE_CLOB_TABLE 
    WHERE MESSAGE_ID in CLOB_ID;
End If;
```

Error: ORA-00932: incosistant datatypes: expected - got CLOB

I also tried writing this using a LISTAGG function but LISTAGG doesnt work with the CLOB values in the MESSAGE_CLOB_TABLE

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: What is type of CLOB_ID in example query and type of CLOB_TEXT field?

Comment: By the way (it's not an answer, but ...) may be you need to add `order by` clause to you query because in current variant there are no guarantee to get a rows from `message_clob_table` at any reasonable order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to concatenate in PL/SQL simplest variant is to loop through all selected records and append all found records to result:

```
create or replace function get_message(p_msg_id in number) return CLOB
is
  v_MessageBody CLOB;
begin
  -- create new instance of temporary CLOB
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_MessageBody, true);

  -- Fill instance with lines
  for cMessages in (
    select clob_text 
    from message_clob_table 
    where message_id = p_msg_id
    order by message_row
  )
  loop
    -- add line
    dbms_lob.append(v_MessageBody, cMessages.clob_text);
  end loop;

  -- return collected lines as single CLOB
  return v_MessageBody;
end;
```

Example above works if type of `CLOB_TEXT` field is `CLOB` and you need to collect only one message. You can test function in [this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea478/2).

If you need to select many messages together based on list of his ID's, function becomes a little bit more complex, but principle remains the same.

Comment: Thank you ThinkJet! This compiled OK but for some reason when I run it, it will populate v_MessageBody with every single value in the clob_text column of the message_clob_table table. Why wouldn't this be filtering out only values in the p_msg_id parameter? Does it have to do with the way createtemporary references v_messageBody?

Comment: Also since p_msg_id can be a comma separated list in my instance, I made the where clause say where message_id in (p_msg_id)

Comment: @Adam You can't just put string into brackets of `message_id in (...)` to test field against list of values. SQL interprets this string as string and knows nothing about it's content. Would it be it comma-separated list or congratulation with birthday. To do so you must first parse this string and extract all the values. And only after that you can use set of extracted values for test.

Comment: Related question on SF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242771/oracle-stored-procedure-with-parameters-for-in-clause