# Sending in comma delimited values to WHERE clause in oracle stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm sending in a comma delimited parameter value to a stored procedure in Oracle. The parameter goes to a `WHERE` clause, I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
valuestring = "ABC123, ABC456, ABC789"



SELECT * 
  FROM Tbl1 
  WHERE column IN (valuestring)
```

Problem is the select statement does not recognize the commas in between the values, it takes it as a single string so when the stored procedure is executed it returns no values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered dynamic queries? Or maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242771/oracle-stored-procedure-with-parameters-for-in-clause?rq=1

Comment: that was the next approach that i had in mind

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, rather than passing in a single string composed of comma-separated values, you would pass in a collection.  If you have something like

```
CREATE TYPE value_tbl AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10);
```

then you could pass that collection into your procedure and use it in a `WHERE` clause

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure_name( p_values IN value_tbl )
AS
  ...
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (SELECT *
              FROM table_name
             WHERE column_name IN (SELECT *
                                     FROM TABLE( p_values )))
  LOOP
    ...
  END LOOP;
END;
```

If you really need to pass in a comma-separated string, you can define the same collection type and then parse the string to populate the collection using something like [Tom Kyte's `str2tbl` function](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:110612348061).  But that's going to be less efficient than passing in a collection to start with.

Comment: There must be a reason why this question comes up so often.  If the front end is VB.net presumably it's not a legacy app.  Perhaps modern developers only learn how to concatenate values and never wonder whether there's a better way to handle multiple values?

Answer (score 0):

Can pass your value string like in given below way. This would convert entire comma separated string in different rows and hence will be easy to use where ever you want.

```
 SELECT trim(x.column_value.extract('e/text()')) COLUMNS
 from t t, table (xmlsequence(xmltype('<e><e>' || replace(valuestring,':','</e><e>')||  
 '</e></e>').extract('e/e'))) x   );
```