# ora-01722 invalid number while updating record

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a table where i have to update multiple records on one button click. I am trying to update multiple record using below simple query.

```
UPDATE tablename SET column1=1 WHERE     
idcolumn IN ('1','2','3')
```

where datatype of idcolumn is Number. If i run this query manually its working perfectly. But if i pass these ('1','2','3') parameteres through procedure then it is showing me below error i.e. (ora-01722 invalid number).

I tried to_number() function but still it is showing me above error.

Proc:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procname(idpara  VARCHAR2,
                                 RCT_OUT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
BEGIN
  UPDATE tablename SET column1 = 1 WHERE idcolumn IN (idpara);
  COMMIT;
  OPEN RCT_OUT FOR
    SELECT 'RECORD UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY' RESULT FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Comment: Show us your procedure code. It looks like you are passing the whole string.

Comment: This sounds weird but almost certainly the problem is related to your data. You need to post a reproducible test case with some sample data which demonstrates the error.

Comment: To me, it sounds like a *varying elements in IN list* problem (as you mentioned a "procedure" and "passing parameters"). Though, to be sure, you should post a test case (as you've already been told).

Comment: `idpara` is a **string** contianing a non-numeric value `1,2,3`. This has come up so many times. Please read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17900024/146325) and also [the thread it duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/242771/146325) for a full range of options.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure does not understand `IN (idpara)` with idpara being `'1','2','3'` as `IN ('1','2','3')` but as `IN (q'!'1','2','3'!')`. In other words, it is not searching for `'1'` and `'2'` and `'3'` but for `'1,2,3'`. But while `'1'` can be converted to a number `'1,2,3'` can not.

Here is a test case for you to show you:

```
select * from dual;
-- X
-- notice I have 'X' in the in list below

set serveroutput on 
declare
idpara varchar2(400) := q'!'X','2','3'!';
v_out varchar2(400);
begin 
select count(*) into v_out from dual where dummy in (idpara);
dbms_output.put_line(v_out);
end;
/
-- 0

declare
idpara varchar2(400) := q'!'X','2','3'!';
v_out varchar2(400);
sql_stmt VARCHAR2(1000) := NULL;
begin 
sql_stmt :='select count(*) from dual where dummy in ('||idpara||')';
execute immediate sql_stmt into v_out;
dbms_output.put_line(v_out);
end;
/
-- 1
```

One solution inside of `procname` would be to build a pl/sql object of numbers and use that in the update. There is a lot of info out there on how to do it. E.g. here [Convert comma separated string to array in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819375/convert-comma-separated-string-to-array-in-pl-sql) And here is info on how to use the object in the IN-clause [Array in IN() clause oracle PLSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515772/array-in-in-clause-oracle-plsql)