# In clause in oracle using in resultset - java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, arraylist

I have a arraylist. The arraylist contains  column values in a specific table.  Eg- 'name' is a column of a table. It has xxx, yyy,zzz values that are in arraylist. My question is, how to add the names in 'in clause' from arraylist.

```
Arraylist<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add('xxx');
list.add('yyy');
list.add('zzz');
Select * from table where name in('xxx','yyy','zzz');
```

Comment: Probably duplicate [Oracle stored procedure with parameters for IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242771/oracle-stored-procedure-with-parameters-for-in-clause?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Can you paste the code on how is the query being fired? PreparedStatement or NormalStatement? Do you use bind variables or want to frame a query directly with these values?

Comment: I'm using prepared statement here. How we can add all values of arraylist in the 'in clause' in  a single fetch? That means, only once I have to execute the query where the query should be framed with arraylist's all values in the 'in clause'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible with the PreparedStatement, but you can use Statement here:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
String req = "Select * from table where name in(";
String params = "";
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (!params.isEmpty())
          params += ",";
        params += "'"+list.get(i)+"'";
    }

req += params + ")";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(req);
```