# Oracle procedure with new type parameter giving ORA-00947 Error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am working on a procedure that accepts a large number of inputs and then returns a populated cursor. The procedure will be called from a Java application. Yes, this would be easy to build as an ad-hoc query, but I am trying to only use proper function/procedure calls in my code.

I will be passing in a unknown number of parameters. I solved this issue with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/243011/6891471) which suggests a new type.

However now I get "[PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00947.php)" error and I can't figure out the issue. I know its concerning the where clause sub-query.

```
DESC BILINGUAL
Name        Null     Type          
----------- -------- ------------- 
KEYFIELD    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(16)  
PURPOSE              VARCHAR2(128) 
CONTENTS_EN NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128) 
CONTENTS_FR NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
```

This is an example of how it will be used and it works.

```
 select keyfield, contents_en, contents_fr
 from bilingual
 where keyfield in ('1111', '1111A');
```

Here is the procedure that I am writing.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE STRING_TABLE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(16);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DOCSADM.BILINGUAL_VALUES (
IN_KEYS string_table,
CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT KEYFIELD, CONTENTS_EN, CONTENTS_FR
    INTO CUR
    FROM BILINGUAL
    WHERE KEYFIELD IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(IN_KEYS));
END BILINGUAL_VALUES;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking in PL/SQL you would open a ref cursor with OPEN .. FOR SELECT .. syntax rather than SELECT .. INTO (although support for CURSOR () functions in SQL means you could technically do either), e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE docsadm.bilingual_values (
   in_keys string_table,
   cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
   OPEN cur FOR
      SELECT keyfield,
             contents_en,
             contents_fr
      FROM   bilingual
      WHERE  keyfield IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE (in_keys));
END bilingual_values;
/
```

Comment: When I used your change, the open cursor instead of select, the issue disappeared. I had not expected the issue would be coming from the cursor so it would have been a very long time before I figured that out. Thank you